# Partial string matching for multiple elements in R

Tags: r, string, grepl

Is it possible to partially match a string containing multiple elements with another string with multiple elements and return `TRUE` or `FALSE` and not a vector?

`Grepl()` can evaluate one element of a string, for example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x="1", y= "1 2 3")

>grepl(dat$x, dat$y)
[1] TRUE
```

But when there are multiple elements, I can't seem to find a solution where I can get a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` evaluation. I applied the same solution by @r2evans from a different problem:

```
dat <- data.frame(x="1 2", y= "1 6 7 8")

> mapply(`%in%`, strsplit(dat$x, "\\D+"), strsplit(dat$y, "\\D+"))
      [,1]
[1,]  TRUE
[2,] FALSE
```

But in this case (if I am understanding this correctly), it is evaluating each element in `dat$x` and returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each element. This is what I want, but to return only a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` statement, such that if any or all elements in `dat$x` is present in `dat$y`, return `TRUE` or `FALSE` and `FALSE` if none are present in `dat$y` such as below:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c("1 2", "3 6 7", "8 5"), y=c("1 6 7 8", "2 9 10", "8 5 3"), result=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))

      x       y result
1   1 2 1 6 7 8   TRUE #Where 1 is present in y (partial)
2 3 6 7  2 9 10  FALSE #Where none is present 
3   8 5   8 5 3   TRUE #where both 8 and 5 are present (full)
```

I have tried to use `paste0` and `collapse='|'` but I don't think my syntax is correct, since the first row evaluation should be `TRUE`.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c("1 2", "3 6 7", "8 5"), y=c("1 6 7 8", "2 9 10", "8 5 3"))

grepl(paste0(dat$x, collapse='|'), dat$y)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any` in `mapply` to return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` value. Using `any` will return `TRUE` if there is more than 0 matches in a string.

```
mapply(function(x, y) any(x %in% y), 
       strsplit(dat$x, "\\s+"), strsplit(dat$y, "\\s+"))

#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Why does `paste0` and `collapse='|' ` not work in this case?

Comment: You don't want `paste0(dat$x, collapse='|')` here, it returns `"1 2|3 6 7|8 5"` as one string. It means it will look for this pattern in all the strings and that is not what you want.